# Solver for over determined non linear system in scipy

Tags: arrays, scipy

May I know the available solvers for solving overdetrmined system of non linear equations. I find that fsolve solves only when the equations and unknown are the same. Please could anyone information on the same.

Comment: May I know why have you tagged `arrays` and `scipy`? And I think if you look for a good answer in a short time ask your question on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If your have a overdetermined system of equations, you need an objective function to characterize how well your parameters solve your equations. Check [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) for methods how to do this with Scipy. `scipy.optimize.leastsq()` is often a good starting point.